# How to get relationship count on a node to different node

Tags: neo4j

here is an example of my problems:

There are some nodes and relationships

- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-01'}]->(Car:Toy)
- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-02'}]->(Car:Toy)
- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-01'}]->(Plane:Toy)
- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-02'}]->(Plane:Toy)
- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-03'}]->(Plane:Toy)
- (Amy:Staff)-[:Sell {date: '2019-11-04'}]->(Plane:Toy)

So how can I get a table like this:

- | Staff |       Toy       | Count |
- |  Amy  | ["Car","Plane"] | [2,4] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should get you going.

```
// find all the sale occurences
MATCH (staff:Staff)-[sale:SELL]-(toy:Toy)

// count the sales per staff and toy ordered by toy
WITH staff.name AS staff, toy.name AS toy, count(sale) AS sales
ORDER BY toy

// aggregate the toys and counts per staff member
RETURN staff, collect(toy) AS toys, collect(sales) AS total_sales
```